# Auto skipping input

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please choose.('e' to encrypt, 'd' to decrypt, 'q' to quit): ");
    String userIn= in.next();
    if(userIn.equals("e")){
        System.out.println("Please enter your text that you want to encrypt: ");
        String userInput = in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Please enter your shift key(0-25): ");
        int userS = in.nextInt();
        if(userS < 0 || userS > 25){
            System.out.print("Invalid shift key, please enter a valid shift key: ");
            userS = in.nextInt();
        }
```

In my above  program at following part of code:

```
System.out.println("Please enter your text that you want to encrypt: ");
                String userInput = in.nextLine();

                System.out.print("Please enter your shift key(0-25): ");
```

It is skipping this `userInput`, it goes over it and asks for the shift key before I enter the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed it (tested in Eclipse):

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please choose.('e' to encrypt, 'd' to decrypt, 'q' to quit): ");
String userInput = in.nextLine();
if (userInput.equals("e"))
{
    System.out.println("Please enter your text that you want to encrypt: ");
    userInput = in.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Please enter your shift key(0-25): ");
    int userS = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
    if (userS < 0 || userS > 25)
    {
        System.out.print("Invalid shift key, please enter a valid shift key: ");
        userS = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
    }
}
in.close();
```

I changed your `userIn` variable to just be `userInput`, since we didn't need it; your `next()` call was also changed to `nextLine()`.

I also changed all your `nextInt()`'s to `nextLine()`'s.  This will help you avoid an `Exception` later on.

Lastly, always close a `Scanner` when you are done with it to conserve system resources.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
String userInput = in.nextLine()
```

to

```
in.nextLine(); String userInput = in.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, change you code to

```
String userInput = in.next();
```

Comment: If you do that then you cant enter a sentence. You can only enter a word.